# Will LSTM cells share weights if they are created by the same function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I am creating a stacked LSTM model using the code below. I have two questions. First, will the two cells share the same weights in the code below? Second, in general when people talk about stacked LSTMs, do all the cells typically share weights?

```
def lstm_cell(size, output_keep_prob):
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(size)
    return tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=output_keep_prob)

with tf.variable_scope("tech_lstm"):
    tech_lstm_okp = tf.placeholder(tf.float64)
    tech_lstm_cells = [lstm_cell(100, tech_lstm_okp) for _ in range(2)]
    stkd_tech_lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(tech_lstm_cells)
    stkd_tech_lstm_init = stkd_tech_lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float64)
    stkd_tech_lstm_outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
                                              stkd_tech_lstm_cell,
                                              tech_data_windows,
                                              initial_state=stkd_tech_lstm_init)
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you misunderstood shared weights. every different cell has own kernel and bias values. shared weights perspective comes from thinking about RNNs as feedforward networks unrolled across time. If the weights were different at each moment in time, this would just be a feedforward network. sharing weights means a cell apply same kernel and bias to all given sequence. so cells dont share weights but is these cells run in order if you want to ask yes first lstmcell gives an output and second lstmcell handle the first lstm cells output

Answer (score 1):

Cells share weights only if they use `tf.get_variable` inside a same `tf.variable_scope` during building. In general, it makes no sense to let stacked cells to share weights so TensorFlow(specifically `tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell`) will create different `tf.variable_scope` for each `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell` you call. Thus if I understand your questions correctly, the answers are
(1) Yes; (2) No.

To see more details, try the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

cells = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(100) for _ in range(2)]
multi_rnn_cells = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells)

batch_size, max_time, dim = 1, 10, 2
rnn_inputs = tf.zeros(shape=(batch_size, max_time, dim))
dynamic_rnn = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_rnn_cells, rnn_inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

for variable in tf.trainable_variables(): print(variable)
```

You will see 4 variables (1 kernel and 1 bias for each cell) inside 2 different `tf.variable_sope`.

When running, the stacked LSTM shares weights in each time step, i.e. stacked RNN shares weights temporally, but not spatially.

Comment: Thank you so much William - great explanation. I upvoted, but don't have enough rep for it to be publicly shown unfortunately. Thanks!

Comment: Very glad that I could help :D